# Looping through 2 arrays to compare values c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I've looked around and can't really find the specific answer to this problem I have. I have two arrays, one that holds a list of people and another that holds a Person object with a name property. I'm trying to loop through the array of objects and if the value in the .Name of the person equals the corresponding value in the array of strings, then I add 1 to a counter.  I've seen answers given using Linq, but i'm not really familiar with that. Is there a basic way to do this that i'm overlooking or will I need to use Linq. Thanks in advance.
Here's the code I have.

```
int count = 0;

string[] names = new string[]{"John","Jim","Mary","Joan","Tim"};

ObservableCollection<Person> people = (ObservableCollection<Person>)Session["People"];

foreach (var pe in people)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        if (pe.Name == names[i])
            count++;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Just one clarification: you don't "need" to use LINQ for anything. These methods represent just an optimised alternative for certain problems. You can use them to write less code or, in certain contexts, to do things quicker. But anything which can be done with LINQ, can be done without it.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `HashSet<string>` to store `names`. It has *O(1)* `Contains` method, when the same `Contains` method on `string[]` is *O(n)*.

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(names);
```

And then

```
foreach (var pe in people)
{
    if(set.Contains(pe.Name))
        count++;  
}
```

or with LINQ

```
count = people.Count(person => set.Contains(person.Name));
```

It will make your solution *O(m)* instead of *O(n*m)*

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
var count = people.Count(pe => names.Contains(pe.Name));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you've posted will work. A simpler version of the loop would be:

```
foreach (var pe in people)
{
    if(names.Contains(pe.Name))
        count++;  
}
```

Using LINQ, it's a one line affair:

```
count = people.Count(person => names.Contains(person.Name));
```

I'd strong recommend taking this opportunity to become familiar with LINQ. It's very powerful and in situations like this results in code that's both more concise and more readable.